# How can I access Deserialize request body object in a Filter?

Tags: servlet-filters, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

We have a dropwizard micro-services, and we need to access POST request body for one of end point in a filter.
How can I access Deserialize request body object in a Filter?

Comment: You would need to access the requests's stream and parse it yourself. What is this for? There are other components in jersey that may help you

Comment: @pandaadb: We need it to add generic validation on request body fields before they land on resource layer so there is no code intrusion. Can you suggest which jersey component I can use for it?

Comment: Jersey supports validation of beans. You can inject your formdata values into a jersey bean and use the java validation framework (i.e. hibernate validators) to validate these beans before they reach the execution of your code

Comment: See for example here for validation details: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.4/docs/manual/validation.html